# Using css/javascript on email payment block (New Order Email)

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, javascript, email, payment-gateway, payment-methods

I'm developing an payment module that shows a button with an action performed with javascript.

This is the code exibed on frontend:

```
<p>             
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function someAction(popup) {
                var url = 'http://url.com/';
                if (popup == true) {
                    window.open(url, 'new_window', 'toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,scrollbars=yes,width=675,height=485');
                }
                else {
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <button type="button" class="form-button" target="new_window" onclick="someAction(true)">
                     <span>Exibir Boleto</span>
        </button>
    </p>
```

On frontend (success page, customer page) shows OK and in backend too, but when this block is sent by email, the code sent is:

```
<td>
    <p>Boleto Bancário</p>
    <p>
       <button type="button">
           <span>Exibir Boleto</span>
       </button>
    </p>
</td>
```

My question is:
What happened to my javascript and part of html properties ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send javascript through e-mails.
I mean...you can but nothing happens. I recommend you to change your button to an `a` tag and just have `<a href="some/url" target="_blank">...</a>`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Now, I divided the info in 2 files: one in /base/default/module/template/info/ and another in /default/default/module/template/info/. In /base/ file, just have the payment method title and a text instructing the customer to login on store and click "My Account/My Purchases", and in /default/ file, the button with action.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking email readers do not allow javascript.